# R Plotly maping issue

Tags: r, plotly, mapping

I am plotting a map with the help of Plotly,
here is the code:

```
plot_ly(spojeno, 
    type = 'scatter',
    color = ~ Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata, 
    split = ~Županija,
    stroke = I("black"), 
    span = I(1),
    text = ~paste("Županija: ", Županija,"<br />", "Ukupna ulaganja, kn: ", formattable::comma(Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata, digits = 0)),
    hoveron = "fills",
    hoverinfo = "text",
    alpha = 1,
    showlegend = FALSE)
```

and here is the map:

[image]

I have a two questions:

1. How do you change the color-fill option in plotly? E.g. to have plasma virids colors or any other.
2. More improantly - how to do increase the differences between regions via "log" or "sqrt" transformation?

For example, both of this issues are easily resolved in ggplot with the - scale_fill_viridis_c - part of the code:

```
  `ggplot(data = spojeno)+
geom_sf(aes(fill=Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata, label=Županija)+
scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans="sqrt", labels = scales::label_comma())`
```

Namely, the scale_fill_virids part of the code uses trans="sqrt" to emphasize the differences between regions without changing the initial numbers from the df and uses plasma colors.
How to do that in plotly mapping? I know I can put `color = ~ sqrt(Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata)` but that will sqrt the initial number from the data set and I would like them to stay the same in the hoover info and the legend on the right.
Thanks.

Comment: If someone could help with this please. Now I did transform the map with  ` color= ~sqrt(Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata)` and  I kept the original values from the dataset with this   `  colorbar(limits = c(0, 3599859569),
           title = "Ukupna \nvrijednost projekata")`  . However, now my colorbar is not having appropriate colors for values. How is it possible to retain the same numbers on the colorbars as in initial data-set but to do log() transform the number for the colors on the map